# PHP Sorting array with values 0,1,2...8,9,10,11,12 etc

Tags: php, sorting, numeric

My array has values that start as single digits and then increase upto the thousands.

I'd like to sort on $id, but have the results as :

`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15` ....etc

NOT

`0,1,10,11,12,13,14,15,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` ....etc

Is that possible without adjust the values within the array ?

Thanks :)

Comment: show your current code..

Comment: if all you have is an array of numbers, is there a reason sort() doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think

```
 natsort ( array &$array )
```

is the solution.From the php manual:

```
<?php
$array1 = $array2 = array("img12.png", "img10.png", "img2.png", "img1.png");

asort($array1);
echo "Standard sorting\n";
print_r($array1);

natsort($array2);
echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
print_r($array2);
?>

The above example will output:

Standard sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
    [2] => img2.png
)

Natural order sorting
Array
(
    [3] => img1.png
    [2] => img2.png
    [1] => img10.png
    [0] => img12.png
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try that :

```
sort($myarr, SORT_STRING);
```